# How To combining multiple filters in working ffmpeg code

Tags: video, ffmpeg

For a project I'm using FFmpeg to edit a short video. At the moment I'm applying four different lines to accomplice what is want.

1:slow mo                    **>**   input.mp4 - output1.mp4

2:overlay                    **>**   output1.mp4 - output2.mp4

3:fade out to black          **>**   output2.mp4 - output3.mp4

4:add image (company logo)    **>**   output3.mp4 - output.mp4

```
1: ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=0:1.8,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1]; [0:v]trim=1.8:3,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v2]; [0:v]trim=start=3,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v3]; [v2]setpts=PTS/0.22[slowv]; [v1][slowv][v3]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0[out]" -map "[out]" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast output.mp4

2: ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -i overlay.png -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=38:950" -codec:a copy output1.mp4

3: ffmpeg -i output1.mp4 -vf "fade=type=out:duration=0.5:start_time=8.5" -c:a copy output2.mp4

4: ffmpeg -y -i output2.mp4 -i output1.avi -filter_complex "[0:v:0][1:v:0]concat=n=2:v=1[outv]" -map "[outv]" output.mp4
```

**My Question**: How can I combine these four separate lines to one FFmpeg code.